# Why is my React-Native component not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So for context on myself, I've done a good amount of React work, but as far as React Native, I have very little experience. I'm trying to create an app that uses React Navigation to jump page to page. It's also new to me but I read that it's good for native apps.

This is the stack navigator setup. Each component is just a simple function returning it's name in a text tag that is inside of a view tag.

```
return (
  <View>
    <Text>Component</Text>
  </View>
)
```

This is the App.js with the stack navigator

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Main from './src/components/main';
import Nav from './src/components/nav';
import Home from './src/pages/home';
import Group from './src/pages/group.js';
import Profile from './src/pages/profile';
import Calendar from './src/pages/calendar';
import Event from './src/pages/event';
import CreateEvent from './src/pages/create-event';
import CreateGroup from './src/pages/create-group';
import JoinGroup from './src/pages/join-group';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Group" component={Group} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Calendar" component={Calendar} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Event" component={Event} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Create Event" component={CreateEvent} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Create Group" component={CreateGroup} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Join Group" component={JoinGroup} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

It defaults to the home page, which is what I want. However, I tried implementing a button that, upon pressing, would navigate to another page ('group'). The button doesn't show up. No text shows up if I implement a text tag. The component is definitely being imported properly, as the console log shown does print to the console.

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Home(props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button style={{flex: 1, width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'black'}} title="Group" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Group')}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

This is what the home page looks like when the app loads up.
[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjpAA.png)

I've tried looking into it a good amount. I've found multiple sources saying to try { flex: 1 } for styling, that didn't fix it. I've tried capitalizing the file name as well as the component, to no change.

Comment: What console log are you referring to that confirms anything? The `Home` component you show that only renders a button doesn't match your home page screen shot. Are you sure you're running your latest code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavigationContainer should not be inside ScrollView, you should place scrollview in your pages components such as Home, Profile Calender

```
export default function App() {
  return (

      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Group" component={Group} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Calendar" component={Calendar} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Event" component={Event} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Create Event" component={CreateEvent} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Create Group" component={CreateGroup} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Join Group" component={JoinGroup} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

and Home Component

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Home(props) {
  return (
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button style={{flex: 1, width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'black'}} title="Group" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Group')}/>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
  )
}
```